# Can I submit a form without using <input> element, or can the <input> element contains two <p> elements?

Tags: css, html, forms, html-input

Inside a `<form>`, I want to have a `input` of `type=submit` which has a fixed `width`, say `150px`, and which submits this `<form>`. In this button, I want to have text on the extreme left side, and a `>` symbol on the extreme right side, like this:

```
 ---------------------------------
| Let's go                      > |
 ---------------------------------
```

Initially I did it by enclosing the `input` in a `div` and then in CSS, using the `:after` pseudo selector to add the `>` symbol (and gave it a `float:right`) after the `input` . **But the problem with that is that the `form` is Not submitted if the user clicks anywhere in the `div` Except the `input` text.**

I would really like to have two `span`s (one for text and one for `>`) or two `p`'s, but the form has to be submitted, so the `input` has to be used, and `input` can not have `span`s or `p`s etc. inside it.

What should I do?

Comment: Try using a `<button type="submit">` … you can nest elements inside it.

Comment: @Solace, Hope you mainly need without input type="submit" for styling purpose. let us know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<button type="submit></button>` and make it `width: 100%`:

```css
.btn-wide {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.btn-wide .icon {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<br><br><br>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-wide">
  <span class="label">Save</span>
  <i class="icon fa fa-angle-right"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your div

```
<div id="submit" onclick="submitForm()">
```

Javascript

```
function submitForm()
 {
      document.getElementById('YourFormId').submit();
 }
```

Comment: this is not the Solace expect !

Comment: It's one of many solutions she can use. Let Solace decide @Venkatraman

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```css
#target:after{
  content:'>'
}
```

```html
<button id='target' type='submit'>
Let's Go&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
</button>
```

Since you would like fixed width instead this is another solution that involves padding

```css
#target:after{
  content:'>'
}
#target span{
  padding-right:300px;
}
```

```html
<button id='target' type='submit'>
<span>Let's Go</span>
</button>
```

Comment: note I use padding to add some empty spaces in the span